# My Lubuntu broken after "corrupted updates"

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, laptop, updates

Yesterday, I tried to update my Lubuntu 16.04.5 LTS.

But, when my laptop tries to switch off display, the display glitched. Then, I reset my laptop, and looking at grub, there's Ubuntu with newer kernel. I tried to boot from it, but it kernel panics. So, I boot the old kernel, logging in, then my desktop, icons, and picture viewer blanks and doesn't work.

*I can't take screenshots too.*

http://www.iasptk.com/ubuntu-fix-broken-package-best-solution
https://www.ostechnix.com/how-to-fix-broken-ubuntu-os-without-reinstalling-it

There's those solutions on the internet, but I ain't sure they're gonna work. :/

Comment: One thing you might need to do (not uncommon for this issue) is to update BIOS, Video and all other drivers.  BIOS can be done with a USB bootable key. For the other drivers, use the computer manufacturer's support site

Comment: Was the update successful?